# How can I use ratios to set priors on multinomial probabilities?

Tags: probability, multinomial-distribution, prior, hierarchical-bayesian, ratio

I have a vector, $k$, that determines allocation to five pools.

I'd like to set priors on these probabilities, and I can provide informative priors on a few of the ratios, e.g.:

$$ \frac{k1}{k2} \sim \text{beta}(6,1)$$
$$ \frac{k1}{k3} \sim \text{beta}(2,12)$$
$$ \frac{k1+k2+k3}{k4+k5} \sim \text{beta}(50,1)$$
$$ \frac{k4}{k5} \sim \text{beta}(1,1)$$

The fact that these values are all correlated makes it unclear how I can start with these priors and then sample $k$ from a multinomial distribution.

Are there any good papers or common methods for doing so?

Comment: There is not enough information for priors. You need also some priors for k1+k2+k3+k4+k5, or for k1 etc.

Comment: @user31264 I don't have any additional information to set informative priors - the additional ones can be flat (e.g. $k1\sim(\text{beta}(1,1)$)

Comment: So you (1) have an information like k1∼(beta(1,1)), or (2) have no any additional information?

Comment: @user31264 I meant (2), that I don't have any additional information, and I can state this lack of information as, e.g., $k1\sim\text{beta}(1,1)$. However, that is not true. I know k1 is not 0 or 1, and would probably be closer to $k1\sim\text{beta}(1,3)$. So maybe I should say that I can come up with priors for other parameters that I need, but the ones I listed are where I am starting.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but I afraid that without any additional information, you cannot obtain the priors.

Comment: @user31264 how much more / what additional information is required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17613/discussion-between-david-and-user31264).

Comment: Can you clarify a little more? You have a random vector $(k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5)$. What are the possible values for the $k_i$'s? What do they mean in your problem?

Comment: @zen the meaning of k is the proportional allocation of resource to different pools (specifically carbon to leaves, roots, stems, etc). Technically I'd say that 'possible' values are [0,1], though I know they are more constrained than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to sample $k$, then this is easy from the distributions given (plus a distribution for $k1$).  The procedure is:

1. Draw $k1$.
2. Draw $b2 \sim {\rm beta}(6,1)$ and set $k2 = \frac{k1}{b2}$.
3. Draw $b3 \sim {\rm beta}(2,12)$ and set $k3 = \frac{k1}{b3}$.
4. Draw $b4 \sim {\rm beta}(50,1)$ and $b5 \sim {\rm beta}(1,1)$ then solve the system
   $$
   k4+k5 = \frac{k1+k2+k3}{b4}
   \\
   k5 = \frac{k4}{b5}
   $$
   whose solution is $k5 = \frac{k1+k2+k3}{b4(1+b5)}$, $k4 = b5 k5$.
5. Finally, if any of the $k$'s are larger than 1, reject the sample and start over.\

You could avoid the rejection step by noting that all of the later $k$'s scale linearly with $k1$.  So once you've got $(b2, ..., b5)$, find the range of $k1$ values that ensure everyone is less than 1 and draw $k1$ within this range.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Dirichlet distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution

It's a generalization of the Beta distribution and is ideal for modeling beliefs about multinomial probabilities.